# Hibernate doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 16.10!

Tags: hibernate

I've been looking for a while, for a good solution to my hibernate problem in Ubuntu 16.10.  I have searched a lot of sites, and one solution was to  modify the file `com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`.  I've included the contents of the file here:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After that, I reboot as they suggest to do. Then the hibernate button in the top panel showed up, and when I click on it to make the laptop hibernate, it works. The laptop shutdown, but the problem shows up when I try to wake it up. The laptop turns on, till the purple screen, then the laptop reboots, and I lost all my work.  So I had to start over again... :(

Any help for this problem?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about *creating* (not modifying) the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`, what you did is not sufficient. Please see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) in the Ubuntu Desktop Guide about what the contents should look like.